# getting exception org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException:

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
@Transactional
public List<FormFields> findFormFieldsByFormFieldIds(
        List<Integer> formFiledsIds) {
    try {
        logger.info("############### findFormFieldsByFormFieldIds dao called ################");
        System.out.println("############### getDashboardXFieldByDashboardIds size : "+formFiledsIds.size());
        Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(FormFields.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.in("fieldId", formFiledsIds)).addOrder(Order.asc("sequenceNo"));
        List<FormFields> list = criteria.list();
        logger.info("############### getDashboardXFieldByDashboardIds size : "+list.size());
        System.out.println("############### getDashboardXFieldByDashboardIds size : "+list.size());
        return list;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Is there any thing wrong in above code? I got below error

> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use near ') order by this_.sequence_no
>   asc' at line 1

Comment: You can post your query?

Comment: perhaps is sequence_no a reserved word?

Comment: sequenceNo is a attribute of the table FormFields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `formFiledsIds` mus not be empty. I had such error when nothing was sent in the list.

Just check the list size and if it's empty return empty list as result.

Comment: Thank you so much it as you say i checked and i got formFieldsIds empty thats why i get this  issue thank you so much....